# Printers deployed through GPO disappear on terminal server

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2019, print-server, roaming-profile

Windows Server 2012  **Print Server** and Domain Controller.

**Printers deployed with GPO**, per user and per machine, to Windows Server 2019 **Terminal Server**.

1. Main issue:
   Every time I logon to Terminal **All/most printers disappear**. Seems it uninstalls one by one after logoff. After logoff, If I wait 10 minutes, seven out of 16 of them disappear.

If I wait two hours all of them disappear.

2. Other symptom:
   Even after fresh user logon next morning, **it takes ages for the GPO to get the printers back** and use them, about 15-20 minutes.

The printers appear slowly in Unspecified Devices Control panel/Device and Printers, and slowly they move to Installed printers one by one.

Users are configured to use roaming profiles and folder redirection. Files stored on Domain controller.

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

Comment: When you say that the printers are deployed with GPO, exactly how are they being deployed with GPO?

Comment: Hi, not sure what exact information you are looking for , but:
- Print server role installed on Domain controller, created GPO policy "Printers" , set to all domain users, linked to object of my Terminal Server. Then went to Print server, installed all the printers, then Deploy with GPO, found this GPO I created, set to both per machine GPO and users GPO.